# Magento URL adding random string

Tags: string, url, magento

Currently have a Magento install running which seems to be printing #.UD3vymhSSYV at the end of every product URL. I assumed I could remove it using the htaccess file, however whenever this is done it generates a different random code.

http://domainname.com/gentlemans-tall-coat-wallet#.UD3vymhSSYV

As you can see above. Im just stumped not sure where it is coming from or how to get rid of it.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER IS POSSIBLY WRONG:**

Harmless - you has some ADDTHIS extension added.

Their URLs are like: http://www.addthis.com/browser-extensions#.UD4zyRVFcal

No further action needed but you may want to get rid of the 'addthis' stalker code.

**THIS ANSWER IS MOSTLY WRONG:**

That does not look like a Magento SID string to me.

You may have a compromised server with someone able to write/inject *stuff* into your index.php./.htaccess

Fire up the site on localhost and make sure that install files are as they should be, particularly index.php and .htaccess.

The server may be compromised with a common attack on whatever else is on the box, e.g. Wordpress, Expression Engine or anything else with known vulnerabilities.

As for what the anchor string does, this may not be obvious to you but could be just for the search engines to pick up - check your site isn't a 'viagra' site on Google.

Don't panic though - it is unlikely that the DB of Magento is compromised.

Comment: Okay thanks i will check this. I have tried googling the string but can't find anything in relation to it. I will also check the DB thanks for the reply.

Comment: Heh, eliminated that last week. It's a configuration line to force tracking through AddThis for URLs pasted into blog articles, etc. Remove the data_track_addressbar config line from the tracking spew javacode.

Comment: Thanks very much. thats sorted it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is done by addthis script.

See how to remove :
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1013558-removing-all-hashtags-anchors-weird-codes-from-your-urls#.UrGWX_QW314